# $1 + \frac1{2+\frac1{2}} + \dots $ diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, continued-fractions

Let $\{ s_n\}$ be an infinite sequence with
$$s_1 = 1$$
$$s_2=\frac1{2+\frac12}$$
$$s_3 = \frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3+\frac13}}$$
$$\vdots$$
I would like to show $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty s_i$ diverges. My attempt:

> Note that $\lim_{k \to \infty}[ 0; k_1,k_2 \dots k_j] = 0$ for all $j>0$ (where $j$ denotes the $j$-th $k$) with $[c_0; c_1,c_2 \dots c_j]$ being continued fraction notation. Then as $n \to \infty$
>   $$s_n = \frac1{n+\frac1{n+\frac1{\ddots}}} \to 0$$
>   Now, I assert $s_n \to \frac{1}{n+s_n}$ as $n \to \infty$. This implies
>   $$s_n \to \frac1n$$
>   Now let $\{ a_m\}$ be an infinite sequence with $a_q = \frac1q$. Given that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ diverges, $s_n \to a_n$, and $a_n,s_n$ are both always positive, it must be the case that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty s_i$ diverges. In other words,
>   $$1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac1{3+\frac1{3+\frac1{3}}} + \frac1{4+\frac1{4+\frac1{4+\frac1{4}}}} \dots$$
>   diverges.

Is my proof sound?

Comment: No, its not sound, because you don't explain what $k_i$s are; $s_n$ is a finite continued fraction expansion, not infinite, and I don't know how $s_n$ can converge to something that includes $n$, as $n\to\infty$

Comment: @CalvinKhor I've clarified what $k_i$s are, although I'm struggling to explain why $s_n \to \frac1{1+s_n}$...

Comment: $\frac{1}{n+\frac1n}<s_n<\frac1n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to say $s_n \gt \frac 1{n+\frac 1n}\gt \frac 1{2n}$ and the sum of $\frac 1{2n} \gt \frac 12\log(n)$ which diverges.

Comment: "the sum of $\frac 1{2n} \gt \frac 12\log(n)$" Well, OK ....

Comment: I would stop at $s_n > \frac1{2n}$

Answer (score 0):

We can reasonably assume that 
$$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3}}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{n+\ldots}}$$ are all bounded above by one 1. It is fairly straightforward to prove that this is monotonic, and this is seen from the fact that  $$1,\ldots,n \in \Bbb{N}.$$

We can now see that if we bound this function from below by 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i+1} $$
And it is now seen that $$\forall i\in \Bbb{N}, \frac{1}{i+1} \lt \frac{1}{i+\frac{1}{i+\ldots}}$$ because we have already said that 
$$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3}}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{n+\ldots}} \lt 1$$
And so we have bounded it below by a divergent series.